# NSFetchedResultsController: no object at index 1 in section at index 0

Tags: ios, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use Magical Record in swift 3. I fairly new to Swift as I've been using objc in the past so I'm getting this error when I'm doing the following:

```
var inAppPackageResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>{
    return InAppPackage.mr_fetchAllSorted(by:"order", ascending: true, with: packagePredicate, groupBy: "name", delegate: self)

}

func returnInfo (type: String, index: IndexPath) -> String {
    print("\(inAppPackageResultsController.fetchedObjects.count)")
    let package = inAppPackageResultsController.object(at: index) as! InAppPackage
```

when I call the returnInfo func, I get the no object at index 1 error but the count of the fetchedObjects is 5.

Comment: maybe your first section has a single element.

Comment: how would I check?

Comment: Best thing would be checking the docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller. I extracted the relevant lines for you:        ```id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];```

Comment: the site doesn't give swift code. Something's wrong with the apple site.